# SQL Server pivot with running tally total row

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014, cumulative-sum

I have a table that I am showing as a pivot. The table has a `category` and `sub-category` column. I want to add a total row for each `category` with a running tally with an initial value coming from another table and adding values from a specific `sub-category`.

Here is full working example to help explain.

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.rawdata
(
      MyMonth       [NVARCHAR](7)  NOT NULL
    , MyCategory    [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
    , MySubCategory [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
    , MyCount       [INT]          NOT NULL
) ON [DEFAULT];

CREATE TABLE dbo.initial
(
      MyCategory    [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
    , MyStart       [INT]          NOT NULL
) ON [DEFAULT];

INSERT INTO dbo.rawdata (MyMonth, MyCategory, MySubCategory, MyCount)
VALUES
    ('2018-12', 'three', 'bravo', 7),
    ('2018-10', 'three', 'echo', 10),
    ('2018-07', 'four', 'echo', 17),
    ('2018-12', 'five', 'bravo', 35),
    ('2018-03', 'three', 'delta', 11),
    ('2018-03', 'six', 'charlie', 1),
    ('2018-09', 'five', 'echo', 11),
    ('2018-12', 'one', 'charlie', 23),
    ('2018-02', 'five', 'charlie', 36),
    ('2018-02', 'three', 'delta', 46),
    ('2018-01', 'two', 'delta', 29),
    ('2018-02', 'four', 'charlie', 15),
    ('2018-11', 'one', 'charlie', 25),
    ('2018-10', 'two', 'bravo', 27),
    ('2018-05', 'four', 'bravo', 17),
    ('2018-12', 'five', 'echo', 12),
    ('2018-05', 'four', 'charlie', 21),
    ('2018-12', 'one', 'delta', 43),
    ('2018-12', 'three', 'bravo', 33),
    ('2018-07', 'two', 'alpha', 32),
    ('2018-11', 'five', 'delta', 44),
    ('2018-01', 'six', 'echo', 38),
    ('2018-08', 'one', 'charlie', 9),
    ('2018-06', 'three', 'echo', 15),
    ('2018-08', 'four', 'bravo', 44),
    ('2018-07', 'six', 'alpha', 50),
    ('2018-12', 'two', 'echo', 4),
    ('2018-04', 'six', 'bravo', 40),
    ('2018-03', 'six', 'delta', 33),
    ('2018-05', 'five', 'alpha', 11),
    ('2018-01', 'three', 'echo', 24),
    ('2018-09', 'five', 'charlie', 10),
    ('2018-09', 'four', 'delta', 36),
    ('2018-04', 'two', 'echo', 13),
    ('2018-02', 'one', 'alpha', 24),
    ('2018-07', 'one', 'bravo', 2),
    ('2018-06', 'five', 'echo', 33),
    ('2018-07', 'five', 'charlie', 46),
    ('2018-12', 'six', 'bravo', 28),
    ('2018-10', 'two', 'echo', 10),
    ('2018-01', 'four', 'delta', 1),
    ('2018-06', 'three', 'bravo', 25),
    ('2018-05', 'four', 'charlie', 27),
    ('2018-04', 'three', 'alpha', 48),
    ('2018-10', 'three', 'alpha', 8),
    ('2018-04', 'two', 'delta', 17),
    ('2018-07', 'five', 'charlie', 2),
    ('2018-03', 'five', 'alpha', 45),
    ('2018-08', 'two', 'charlie', 21),
    ('2018-11', 'three', 'bravo', 32),
    ('2018-07', 'one', 'echo', 34),
    ('2018-12', 'one', 'echo', 21),
    ('2018-08', 'two', 'delta', 8),
    ('2018-04', 'three', 'delta', 32),
    ('2018-11', 'five', 'alpha', 23),
    ('2018-03', 'two', 'echo', 16),
    ('2018-02', 'six', 'echo', 35),
    ('2018-11', 'three', 'alpha', 16),
    ('2018-08', 'four', 'alpha', 40),
    ('2018-03', 'one', 'echo', 39),
    ('2018-09', 'one', 'charlie', 22),
    ('2018-06', 'three', 'bravo', 38),
    ('2018-02', 'one', 'bravo', 18),
    ('2018-11', 'four', 'echo', 41),
    ('2018-12', 'three', 'alpha', 49),
    ('2018-02', 'six', 'delta', 24),
    ('2018-09', 'five', 'alpha', 41),
    ('2018-09', 'six', 'delta', 12),
    ('2018-04', 'three', 'delta', 15),
    ('2018-12', 'three', 'delta', 36),
    ('2018-05', 'five', 'delta', 26),
    ('2018-01', 'three', 'echo', 22),
    ('2018-03', 'four', 'delta', 26),
    ('2018-05', 'three', 'echo', 33),
    ('2018-07', 'three', 'bravo', 1),
    ('2018-10', 'four', 'echo', 37),
    ('2018-01', 'three', 'alpha', 32),
    ('2018-04', 'two', 'bravo', 2),
    ('2018-08', 'one', 'bravo', 41),
    ('2018-03', 'three', 'bravo', 40),
    ('2018-07', 'three', 'alpha', 38),
    ('2018-02', 'three', 'bravo', 2),
    ('2018-11', 'six', 'charlie', 17),
    ('2018-08', 'three', 'echo', 5),
    ('2018-02', 'six', 'bravo', 49),
    ('2018-02', 'one', 'alpha', 9),
    ('2018-07', 'five', 'charlie', 26),
    ('2018-05', 'five', 'echo', 7),
    ('2018-11', 'six', 'bravo', 31),
    ('2018-08', 'four', 'alpha', 19),
    ('2018-05', 'one', 'charlie', 30),
    ('2018-05', 'one', 'echo', 31),
    ('2018-01', 'four', 'bravo', 31),
    ('2018-06', 'four', 'alpha', 29),
    ('2018-10', 'one', 'alpha', 45),
    ('2018-04', 'two', 'charlie', 41),
    ('2018-08', 'one', 'delta', 24),
    ('2018-01', 'five', 'bravo', 27),
    ('2018-08', 'two', 'charlie', 43),
    ('2018-02', 'four', 'delta', 19);

INSERT INTO dbo.initial (MyCategory, MyStart)
VALUES
    ('five', 9),
    ('four', 4),
    ('one', 6),
    ('six', 6),
    ('three', 3),
    ('two', 9);
```

My current `pivot` SQL query:

```
SELECT
      MyCategory
    , MySubCategory
    , ISNULL("2018-01", 0) AS "2018-01"
    , ISNULL("2018-02", 0) AS "2018-02"
    , ISNULL("2018-03", 0) AS "2018-03"
    , ISNULL("2018-04", 0) AS "2018-04"
    , ISNULL("2018-05", 0) AS "2018-05"
    , ISNULL("2018-06", 0) AS "2018-06"
    , ISNULL("2018-07", 0) AS "2018-07"
    , ISNULL("2018-08", 0) AS "2018-08"
    , ISNULL("2018-09", 0) AS "2018-09"
    , ISNULL("2018-10", 0) AS "2018-10"
    , ISNULL("2018-11", 0) AS "2018-11"
    , ISNULL("2018-12", 0) AS "2018-12"
FROM
    (SELECT
         MyCategory
         , MySubCategory
         , MyMonth
         , MyCount
     FROM 
         dbo.rawdata) SourceTable
PIVOT
    (SUM(MyCount)
     FOR MyMonth IN ("2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12")
    ) PivotTable
ORDER BY 
    MyCategory, MySubCategory;
```

PIVOT output:

```
    +------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | MYCATEGORY | MYSUBCATEGORY | JAN-18 | FEB-18 | MAR-18 | APR-18 | MAY-18 | JUN-18 | JUL-18 | AUG-18 | SEP-18 | OCT-18 | NOV-18 | DEC-18 |
    +------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    | five       | alpha         | 0      | 0      | 45     | 0      | 11     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 41     | 0      | 23     | 0      |
    | five       | bravo         | 27     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 35     |
    | five       | charlie       | 0      | 36     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 74     | 0      | 10     | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | five       | delta         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 26     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 44     | 0      |
    | five       | echo          | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 7      | 33     | 0      | 0      | 11     | 0      | 0      | 12     |
    | four       | alpha         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 29     | 0      | 59     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | four       | bravo         | 31     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 17     | 0      | 0      | 44     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | four       | charlie       | 0      | 15     | 0      | 0      | 48     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | four       | delta         | 1      | 19     | 26     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 36     | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | four       | echo          | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 17     | 0      | 0      | 37     | 41     | 0      |
    | one        | alpha         | 0      | 33     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 45     | 0      | 0      |
    | one        | bravo         | 0      | 18     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 2      | 41     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | one        | charlie       | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 30     | 0      | 0      | 9      | 22     | 0      | 25     | 23     |
    | one        | delta         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 24     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 43     |
    | one        | echo          | 0      | 0      | 39     | 0      | 31     | 0      | 34     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 21     |
    | six        | alpha         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 50     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | six        | bravo         | 0      | 49     | 0      | 40     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 31     | 28     |
    | six        | charlie       | 0      | 0      | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 17     | 0      |
    | six        | delta         | 0      | 24     | 33     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 12     | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | six        | echo          | 38     | 35     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | three      | alpha         | 32     | 0      | 0      | 48     | 0      | 0      | 38     | 0      | 0      | 8      | 16     | 49     |
    | three      | bravo         | 0      | 2      | 40     | 0      | 0      | 63     | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 32     | 40     |
    | three      | delta         | 0      | 46     | 11     | 47     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 36     |
    | three      | echo          | 46     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 33     | 15     | 0      | 5      | 0      | 10     | 0      | 0      |
    | two        | alpha         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 32     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | two        | bravo         | 0      | 0      | 0      | 2      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 27     | 0      | 0      |
    | two        | charlie       | 0      | 0      | 0      | 41     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 64     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | two        | delta         | 29     | 0      | 0      | 17     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 8      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      |
    | two        | echo          | 0      | 0      | 16     | 13     | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 10     | 0      | 4      |
    +------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Desired output:

For each `category`, add a Total row. The value for the **first** month will get the starting value from the `dbo.initial` table **plus** the value of the `alpha` `sub-category`. The value for the next month will take the value from the previous month plus the `alpha` `sub-category`. If a `category` doesn't have a `alpha` `sub-category` then use 0.

Desired output example:

I'm showing only a few rows and months for the sake of brevity and I am showing the math for example purposes.

```
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| MYCATEGORY | MYSUBCATEGORY | INITIAL | JAN-18  | FEB-18  | MAR-18  |
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| five       | alpha         |         | 0       | 0       | 45      |
| five       | bravo         | 27      | 0       | 0       |         |
| five       | ...snippit... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |
| five       | total         | 9       | 9+0=9   | 9+0=9   | 9+45=54 |
| three      | alpha         |         | 32      | 0       | 0       |
| three      | delta         | 0       | 46      | 11      | 47      |
| five       | ...snippit... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |
| three      | total         | 3       | 3+32=35 | 35+0=35 | 35+0=35 |
+------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: why not to have these columns on the same row?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. write an Pivot `CTE`, then `UNION ALL` `CTE` result set and `CTE` totle result set.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT  
    MyCategory
    , MySubCategory
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-01', MyCount,0) AS 'col01'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-02', MyCount,0) AS 'col02'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-03', MyCount,0) AS 'col03'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-04', MyCount,0) AS 'col04'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-05', MyCount,0) AS 'col05'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-06', MyCount,0) AS 'col06'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-07', MyCount,0) AS 'col07'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-08', MyCount,0) AS 'col08'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-09', MyCount,0) AS 'col09'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-10', MyCount,0) AS 'col10'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-11', MyCount,0) AS 'col11'
    , IIF(MyMonth ='2018-12', MyCount,0) AS 'col12'
  FROM  dbo.rawdata
)
SELECT t.*,i.MyStart
FROM 
(
select 
     MyCategory
    ,MySubCategory
    ,col01  AS '2018-01'
    ,col02  AS '2018-02'
    ,col03  AS '2018-03'
    ,col04  AS '2018-04'
    ,col05  AS '2018-05'
    ,col06  AS '2018-06'
    ,col07  AS '2018-07'
    ,col08  AS '2018-08'
    ,col09  AS '2018-09'
    ,col10  AS '2018-10'
    ,col11  AS '2018-11'
    ,col12  AS '2018-12'
from CTE t
union all 
select MyCategory,
         'totle' as MySubCategory,
          SUM(col01),
          SUM(col01 + col02),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07 +col08),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07 +col08 +col09),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07 +col08 +col09 +col10),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07 +col08 +col09 +col10 +col11),
          SUM(col01 + col02+ col03 +col04 +col05 + col06 +col07 +col08 +col09 +col10 +col11+col12)
  from CTE
  GROUP BY MyCategory
) t inner join dbo.initial i on t.MyCategory = i.MyCategory
order by MyCategory,MySubCategory
```

**Results**:

```
| MyCategory | MySubCategory | 2018-01 | 2018-02 | 2018-03 | 2018-04 | 2018-05 | 2018-06 | 2018-07 | 2018-08 | 2018-09 | 2018-10 | 2018-11 | 2018-12 | MyStart |
|------------|---------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|       five |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      11 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         alpha |       0 |       0 |      45 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      23 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      41 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         bravo |      27 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      35 |       9 |
|       five |       charlie |       0 |      36 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      10 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      46 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      26 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      26 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      44 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       7 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      33 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      12 |       9 |
|       five |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      11 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|       five |         totle |      27 |      63 |     108 |     108 |     152 |     185 |     259 |     259 |     321 |     321 |     388 |     435 |       9 |
|       four |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      40 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      19 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      29 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         bravo |      31 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      44 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      17 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      21 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |       charlie |       0 |      15 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      27 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      36 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         delta |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         delta |       0 |       0 |      26 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         delta |       0 |      19 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      37 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      41 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      17 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |
|       four |         totle |      32 |      66 |      92 |      92 |     157 |     186 |     203 |     306 |     342 |     379 |     420 |     420 |       4 |
|        one |         alpha |       0 |      24 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      45 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         alpha |       0 |       9 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         bravo |       0 |      18 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      41 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      30 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      22 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      23 |       6 |
|        one |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      25 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      43 |       6 |
|        one |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      24 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      31 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      34 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      21 |       6 |
|        one |          echo |       0 |       0 |      39 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        one |         totle |       0 |      51 |      90 |      90 |     151 |     151 |     187 |     261 |     283 |     328 |     353 |     440 |       6 |
|        six |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      50 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |      40 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      28 |       6 |
|        six |         bravo |       0 |      49 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      31 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      17 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         delta |       0 |       0 |      33 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         delta |       0 |      24 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      12 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |          echo |       0 |      35 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |          echo |      38 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       6 |
|        six |         totle |      38 |     146 |     180 |     220 |     220 |     220 |     270 |     270 |     282 |     282 |     330 |     358 |       6 |
|      three |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |      48 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       8 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      16 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      49 |       3 |
|      three |         alpha |      32 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      38 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |      40 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      25 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      38 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      33 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      32 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       7 |       3 |
|      three |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |      32 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         delta |       0 |       0 |      11 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         delta |       0 |      46 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |      15 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      36 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |      22 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      33 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      15 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |      24 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       5 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      10 |       0 |       0 |       3 |
|      three |         totle |      78 |     126 |     177 |     272 |     305 |     383 |     422 |     427 |     427 |     445 |     493 |     618 |       3 |
|        two |         alpha |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      32 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      27 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         bravo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       2 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |      41 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      43 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |       charlie |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      21 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       8 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         delta |       0 |       0 |       0 |      17 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         delta |      29 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |          echo |       0 |       0 |      16 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       4 |       9 |
|        two |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |      13 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |          echo |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |      10 |       0 |       0 |       9 |
|        two |         totle |      29 |      29 |      45 |     118 |     118 |     118 |     150 |     222 |     222 |     259 |     259 |     263 |       9 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4720/1)